# Concatenate panda dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df

```
 A B C Rest
 1 2 3 b'\n\x06\x06
 2 3 4 b'\n\x06\x07
 3 3 3 b'\n\x06\x08 
 4 4 4 b'\n\x06\x09
```

I want to send 'Rest' as input to one function that should return me another dataframe that I want to concatenate, so that result will be something like this.

```
A B C Rest         D   E     F   G 
1 2 3 b'\n\x06\x06 6   6     Nan Nan
2 3 4 b'\n\x06\x07 6   7     Nan Nan
3 3 3 b'\n\x06\x08 Nan Nan   6   8
4 4 4 b'\n\x06\x09 Nan Nan   6   9
```

Here is what I am doing

```
my_dtype = [
            ('D', np.uint8),
            ('E', np.uint8),
            ]
my_dtype2 = [
            ('F', np.uint8),
            ('G', np.uint8),
            ]
                    
def parseME1(self,values):
    ser = (np.fromstring(values,my_dtype))
    seri = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ser)
    return seri
    
def parseME2(self,values):
    ser = (np.fromstring(values,my_dtype2))
    seri = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ser)
    return seri
    
#create another dataframes based on value of A


df2 = df.loc[df['A'] <= 2]
and then passes to 
df = pd.concat([df, df2.pop("Rest").apply(parseME1)], axis=1)

df3 = df.loc[df['A'] >= 2]
df = pd.concat([df, df3.pop("Rest").apply(parseME2)], axis=1)
```

But my df is not changed. Could someone please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First add [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for function for convert 1 row `DataFrame`s to `Series` and then change second condition to `df['A'] > 2` instead `df['A'] >= 2`:

```
def parseME1(values):
    ser = (np.fromstring(values,my_dtype))
    seri = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ser).iloc[0]
    return seri
    
def parseME2(values):
    ser = (np.fromstring(values,my_dtype2))
    seri = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ser).iloc[0]
    return seri

df2 = df.loc[df['A'] <= 2]
# and then passes to 
df = pd.concat([df, df2.pop("Rest").apply(parseME1)], axis=1)

df3 = df.loc[df['A'] > 2]
df = pd.concat([df, df3.pop("Rest").apply(parseME2)], axis=1)

print (df)
   A  B  C         Rest    D    E    F    G
0  1  2  3  b'\x06\x06'  6.0  6.0  NaN  NaN
1  2  3  4  b'\x06\x07'  6.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
2  3  3  3  b'\x06\x08'  NaN  NaN  6.0  8.0
3  4  4  4    b'\x06\t'  NaN  NaN  6.0  9.0
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But it is very slow. I have around 500k records and it takes forever. Is there something that could be done to make it faster?

Comment: @saras - there are alwasy 2 values in column `Rest` ?

Comment: No the number of columns are variable. In my real situation df has around 50 columns and the Rest can have another 40-45 columns

Comment: @saras - Then no idea about faster processing, because for each value are run a bit complicated function, so I am afraid it cannot be very fast for 500k rows.